# how to generate cvblob.lib?

Tags: c, opencv

These errors occurred when I tried to compile my code:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvFilterByArea referenced in function _main
 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvRenderBlobs referenced in function _main
 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _cvLabel referenced in function _main

I found a post stating that I should place cvblob.lib in the input linker but I'm having troubles generating cvblob.lib. I'm at a dead end right now. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cvBlob](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/) is not a part of OpenCV. It's an external library that needs to be downloaded,  compiled and installed on your system.

Check: [How to Install](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/wiki/HowToInstall) and [How to Use](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/wiki/HowToUse).